# how to wait check ajax request has completed before other element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have following code, where for each Image it makes ajax call. but my problem is like when it make ajax call for first image,at that time without waiting for respose it invokes for the second.so it hasn't get effect of first call,means I missed the first call effect. similary without waiting for second it is inovking for third,...

so how to wait in above each function until response come?

```
jQuery('.xxx img[src*="mainimage"]').each(function () {
        vobj = $(this);
        var inmainurl = 'https://xxx.kki/api/oembed.json?url=' + $(this).attr('src');
        $.ajax({
            url: inmainurl,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (result) {


                $(vobj).attr('src',result.thumbnail_url);

            }
        });


    });
```

Comment: You are declaring vobj globaly that's the problem

Comment: @RolandStarke-if  not used that Global variable then in success  $(vobj).attr('src',result.thumbnail_url);  is not working.

Comment: @RolandStarke, That is invalid point..

Comment: @RolandStarke, In `each`, value of variable `vobj` will be nothing but a current element. It has nothing to do with the global variable. _Note: Use of global variables should be avoided_

Comment: Try it out then, even if you use `var`, success callback will always take last element as by the time success callback executes, `forEach` iteration is completed..

Answer (score 1):

You should use a **recursive function** for these purposes. Basic example ([jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kmsdev/gvrhpnpv/1/)):

```
var myMethod = function(index){
    var total_images = $('img').length;
    if( index == total_images ) return; // job finished
    var current_image = index || 0;
    $.ajax({
        /*...*/
        success: function(/*...*/){
            /*...*/
            myMethod(current_image + 1);
        }
    });
};

myMethod();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could make it synchronous by adding `async: false` to the ajax parameters. Then you can call them one after the other.

Or, if you want a bit more flexibility, put the ajax call into a function, passing in the image to load. Then in the "success" method of the ajax call, call the function again, passing in the next image name. You'll need some sort of list of image names so that the recursive calls can work out the next image to pass in, in each case.

Comment: *Note: Starting with Gecko 30.0 (Firefox 30.0 / Thunderbird 30.0 / SeaMonkey 2.27), synchronous requests on the main thread have been deprecated due to the negative effects to the user experience.* https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Synchronous_and_Asynchronous_Requests#Synchronous_request

Answer (score 0):

After every ajax success callback, set some `data-*` attribute to loaded element and call the same function again.

Try this:

```js
function loadOnlyOneImage() {
  var vobj = $('.xxx img[src*="mainimage"][data-loaded!="true"]:first');
  if (vobj.length) {
    var inmainurl = 'https://xxx.kki/api/oembed.json?url=' + vobj.attr('src');
    $.ajax({
      url: inmainurl,
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(result) {
        vobj.attr('src', result.thumbnail_url);
        vobj.attr('data-loaded', true);
        loadOnlyOneImage();
      }
    });
  }
}
loadOnlyOneImage();
```